# Editing Grub.cfg

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning

I have two questions.

1. Where is grub.cfg located?

   - Ubuntu `/` is mounted on `/dev/sda6`
   - Fedora `/` is mounted on `/dev/sda8`
2. How should I edit `grub.cfg` so that when I choose Ubuntu (out of Ubuntu and Windows 7), it asks me to choose between Ubuntu and Fedora.

Comment: Do you mean `grub.cfg`? It is located in /boot/grub/grub.cfg, but you **should NOT** modify it. You can change some settings in /etc/default/grub and run `sudo update-grub` afterwards.

Comment: Eduardo, exactly right but it's never edited directly, you need /etc/default/grub  and run update-grub command afterwards.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu and what version of Grub are you using. It should not be necessary to chainload Fedora this way if you run `sudo update-grub` on recent versions of Grub2 as Fedora should be detected and Grub should show an option for Ubuntu, Fedora, and Windows7.

Comment: Instead of editing `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, you should edit `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`

Comment: If I can make sense of what you're asking, you're asking what you need to add to `grub.cfg` so that it works for both Ubuntu and Fedora, which uses different assignments for the partitions? You need to use UUIDs as they won't change and should (will) be unique.

Comment: @KenSharp you have got it right... can u elaborate on your answer

Comment: @mchid ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit and grub-install (GRUB) 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.7

Comment: Does grub currently show an option for Fedora?

Comment: yeah but it shows all the three at the same time... i had seen in some workshop... the guy editing grub.cfg file after which the , at first, only 2 options , ie ubnutu n win7 r displayed n ubuntu is chosem it further gives the option for ubuntu or fedora.. he also explained to di this with windows by editing boot.ini but let that be for now

Comment: I've never done this but I believe this is called "chainloading" and there are a few tutorials out there but beware that some of them are for the old version of Grub and not for Grub2. Additionally, your entry should go in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` and you **should not** erase the line `exec tail -n +3 $0` at the top of the file.

Answer (score 0):

1) grub.cfg is located at /boot/grub/grub.cfg (however, editing this file manually isn't normally recommended as a normal kernel update can break your customizations and errors can leave you with a unbootable system). This is not to say that there is no reason to do so. I can think of 1 [example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323749/background-image-manual-grub-cfg) off the top of my head where it's not only desirable but necessary.

2) What your asking about here is a submenu. The default operation would be to present a menu with all three options rather than place Ubuntu and Fedora in a submenu titled Ubuntu. One easy way to edit grub menus is to use the package [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer) which allows for numerous cutomizations including background images, default boot selection, timeout, sub menus, etc, etc. It's simple to use for the novice but powerful enough to satisfy almost everyone. How to install instructions are on the page linked above.